# every planar graph can be expressed as a union of five edge-disjoint forests

Tags: graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs

How can I prove that every planar graph can be expressed as a union of (maximum) five edge-disjoint forests?

Only thing I can think about is going somehow like the $5$ color theorem but I get stuck in the middle. Or with induction, but still something doesn't fit. Can you help?

Comment: In fact, every planar graph is a union of at most *three* forests, see, for instance, a solution of Problem 4 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~jhicks/classes/spring15math191/math191problemsets.pdf).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2791039/14578

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use induction on the number of vertices. A planar graph $G$ has at most $3|V|-6$ edges, so there is at least one vertex $v$ of degree 5 or less.

Let $\{w_1,\ldots, w_j\}$; $j \le 5$ be $v$'s neighbors in $G$.

Then let $F_1,\ldots, F_5$ be the 5 edge-disjoint forests (some may be empty) such that $\cup_{j=1}^5 F_i = E(G \setminus \{v\})$. By induction such $F_1,\ldots, F_5$ exist.

Then for each $i \le j$ set $F'_i = F_i + \{v,w_i\}$, and (if $j$ is strictly less than 5) for each $i \in \{j+1,\ldots, 5\}$ set $F'_i=F_i$. Then each $F'_i$ is also a forest, and that each edge of $G$ is in one of the $F'_i$s. Make sure you can see why.

The above is about your answer (or at least enough for you to finish the proof).

Comment: The only thing that I don't really get is this:
"By induction such F1,…,F5 exist."

Comment: By induction on the number of vertices. We assume that there is such an edge decomposition for every planar graph $G'$ with fewer vertices than $G$ has. But $G \setminus \{v\}$ is planar and has one fewer vertex than $G$, so by our induction hypothesis there exists such an edge-decomposition, hence there exist $F_1,\ldots, F_5$..

Comment: could you be more specific? What's the base of the induction?

Comment: Any planar graph $G$ with 3 or fewer vertices is a base. Then $E(G)$ can be partitioned into forests $F_1,\ldots, F_5$ (some of the $F_i$s here may be empty and that is fine)

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but now that we have made the assumption that there is such an edge decomposition for every planar graph G′ with fewer vertices than  G  has, shouldn't we prove something  in order to say that our assumption is right?

Comment: No need, as it is "obvious" that if $G$ has only 3 vertices its edge-set can be partitioned as specified above. (Make sure you can see for yourself)

Comment: In proof by induction, after you *observe* the base case (here a planar graph with 3 vertices), you assume that your claim has already been shown for graphs $G'$ with fewer vertices than $G$ has and use to show that the claim holds for $G$ as well. Think of it as a cascade of dominos. The base case is the first domino toppling, so to show that the whole chain of dominos fall, you just have to show that the $n$th domino will hit the $n+1$-th domino for each $n$.

Answer (score 2):

More generally any graph $G$ can be expressed as a union of $\left\lceil\frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|-1}\right\rceil$ edge-disjoint forests since for every forrest $F\subseteq G$ with $V(F)=V(G)$ we have $|E(F\setminus G)|\leq |E(G)|-|V(G)|+1$. Thus if we let $F_{i+1}$ be any forrest spanning $G\setminus F_i$ with $F_0=\emptyset$ then the sequence terminates at an integer $n\leq \left\lceil\frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|-1}\right\rceil$ so we get $n$ edge disjoint forrests $F_1,\ldots F_n$ satisfying $G=\cup_{k=1}^nF_k$.

In your particular case note that if $G$ is planar then $\left\lceil\frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|-1}\right\rceil\leq 3$  thus every planar graph can be expressed as a union of $3$ edge-disjoint forests.